# Trim off 1st Comma from Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @WithdrawnClasses VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @WithdrawnClasses = COALESCE(@WithdrawnClasses + ', ', '') + fcd.ClassNbr
FROM XR.FrmCM9Details fcd
INNER JOIN XR.FrmCM9 fc ON fcd.FrmCM9FK = fc.Id
AND fc.FrmMstFK = '00775549-4EB9-478B-AFD5-5667BD9AA7EE'
SELECT @WithdrawnClasses
```

If I run this query i will return output as , 01, 03, 05, 29, 35

So is there any way that I take trim off 1st comma using above query. So the result should be as 01, 03, 05, 29, 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select @WithdrawnClasses =STUFF(@WithdrawnClasses , 1, 1, '')
```

Or remove the assign statement of variable `@WithdrawnClasses`

```
DECLARE @WithdrawnClasses VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
  @WithdrawnClasses = COALESCE(@WithdrawnClasses + ', ', '') + fcd.ClassNbr
FROM XR.FrmCM9Details fcd
INNER JOIN XR.FrmCM9 fc ON fcd.FrmCM9FK = fc.Id
  AND fc.FrmMstFK = '00775549-4EB9-478B-AFD5-5667BD9AA7EE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @WithdrawnClasses=SUBSTRING(@WithdrawnClasses,1,LEN(@WithdrawnClasses)-1)
```